# Another proof about inequality?

Tags: inequality

Is the inequality  $ |f(x)|  > g(x) $ equivalent to $ f(x) > g(x) $ OR $  - f(x) > g(x)  $ in the set of all real numbers?

My answer is yes.

I tried. First, I proof 
$$|f(x)| <g(x) \Leftrightarrow -g(x)  < f(x) < g(x).  $$

- If $ g(x) \leqslant 0 $, then the inequality $ |f(x)| <g(x) $ has no solution and  $ -g(x)  < f(x) < g(x) $ has no solution too.
- If $ g(x) > 0 $, from $ |f(x)| <g(x) $, we have $ f^2(x) < g^2(x) $, and then $ -g(x)  < f(x) < g(x) $.

Similarly, we have 
$$|f(x)| \leqslant g(x) \Leftrightarrow -g(x)  \leqslant  f(x) \leqslant g(x).  $$

Negate the sentence  $ |f(x)|  \leqslant g(x) $ is $ |f(x)|  > g(x) $, therefore $ |f(x)|  > g(x) $ is equivalent to $ f(x) > g(x) $ or $  - f(x)  > g(x)  $.

Am I true? Is there another proof?

Comment: Your proof is correct, but the first part with strict inequality $|f(x)| <g(x)$ is of no use here.

Comment: How about another way?

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the point of such a long proof:
$$|f(x)|=\begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if $f(x)\ge 0$}\\ -f(x) &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So $|f(x)|>g(x)$ means $f(x)>g(x)$ if $f(x)\ge 0$, $-f(x)>g(x)$ otherwise.

On the other hand, if the question was about the mutually exclusion, it's clearly false: let $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=-2$, so both |f(x)| and $-f(x)$ are greater than $g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.